# How to make Unity FB.AppRequest reach their receiver?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So I integrated the Facebook Unity SDK version 7.21.2 in Unity 2019.4.8 and setup my app on facebook in development mode.

I am sending an 'Invite' aka AppRequest to a friend that also is part of the app as a developer. I also get a confirmation that the request went out with the facebook user id it was sent to.
But he does not receive anything.

Shouldn't he receive an invite? Does the app have to be reviewed before that works? (Which makes implementing this feature rather hard, since I cannot test it)

Comment: Does he see it under https://www.facebook.com/games/activity . If so it is explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests/

Comment: Nope it does not show up there...